# Is Jesus presently seated on a throne?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, kingdom-of-god, kingdom-of-heaven, throne-of-god

We often say or sing that Jesus is currently enthroned in heaven or seated on His throne in heaven. However, does Jesus instead teach that He won't sit on His throne before the Second Coming (Matt. 19:28; 25:31; Luke 1:32)? Furthermore, don't the Scriptures teach that at present, rather than being on the throne, Jesus is "seated at **the right hand of the throne** of the Majesty in the heavens" (Heb. 8:1, NKJV, emphasis mine; cf. 12:2)? It seems as if He isn't seated on the throne even now but is rather seated *next to* the throne.

Am I missing something? It does seem familiar to me that a verse exists describing Jesus as presently on a throne, but I can't recall where in the Bible, if anywhere, such is said. Do the Scriptures teach that Jesus is on His throne now, or is that only a future event?

**Note:**

I am not looking for "Jesus is outside time anyway" answers, as this type of response distracts from the real issue. Regardless of whether Jesus may perform some acts outside of time, there are clearly events He's done within time, such as coming to the earth. Likewise, Christ's being seated at God's right hand also appears to be an event in time, for example, taking place after His ascension.

Comment: The idea that comes to mind is that of a king and queen; each has a throne and is seated next to the other, but only one is ruler over the kingdom.

Comment: _And he shewed me a pure river of water of life, clear as crystal, proceeding out of the throne of God **and of the Lamb**._ Revelation 22:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Revelation 3:21 (NASB)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%203%3A21&version=NASB), it says,

> The one who overcomes, I will grant to him to sit with Me on My
> throne, as I also overcame and sat with My Father on His throne.

My understanding of "right hand" is "executive officer", like the president or CEO -- the one who does most of the work, but with oversight from the "owner".  Think "right-hand man".

But in the above verse, it is clear that both Jesus and His Father are on the throne together, and since they are two persons of the Trinity which is God, they are in complete unison and harmony, and rule as one ["Hear Oh Israel the Lord thy God is One God." -- Deut. 6:4 KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+6%3A4&version=KJV)

This is also based on a confirmation by God himself relayed by a first-person account in the book, ["Murdered Heiress, Living Witness" by "Petti Wagner"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XW02DC) who has an autobiographical book about her murder and resurrection, and what God taught her about himself on Amazon. This book has forever convinced me 100% that the doctrine of the Trinity is correct, faithful, and true.

So, then, who cares whether Jesus rules, or His Father rules, if they rule together in perfect harmony? In the light of eternity, this is not a question that you really have to worry about.

The final implication of the quoted verse is that **we** get to rule as well! Wow! What an honor!

---

The following excerpt from the above-referenced book, occurs after her resurrection (she had been killed by electroshock therapy machine turned up to maximum.)

> The Spoon
>
> At nine o'clock, God began to instruct me in His plan for my escape. It was totally absurd for me; all my life, I had based every decision on logic. He knew exactly what I was thinking. In fact, His first words were, "As soon as you learn that I am not confined to logic. As He paused, I felt ashamed of my "rational" thought about saving a knife instead of the spoon from the dinner tray. I silently acknowledged Him. I felt immediate, gentle forgiveness flowing through me. Then the Voice continued: "As soon as you learn that I am not confined to logic, that I am supernatural and super-normal, we can work together."
>
> I wanted to ponder those words, but God said, "Let me show you who We are." He hadn't appeared to me in bodily form as Jesus had while I was in that unearthly sphere. However, I instantly saw a ball of light which totally filled and illuminated the dingy room. "We are One - Father, Son, and Holy Ghost," the Voice announced. Then the bright orb split into three separate balls which formed a triangle. "Now we are separate." I knew, like I had experienced total knowledge while in that other dimension, that God the Father was the shining spherical light at the top of the triangle; Jesus was the one below on His right; and the Holy Spirit on His left. Though They spoke as one, each member of the Trinity was identifiable by His distinctive voice. The Father had a deep, booming voice with resonant overtones like I had never heard before. Jesus' voice was tender and compassionate, just like when we sat in the chairs. The Holy Spirit sounded somewhat like the nicest teacher I ever had - who had taught me law and psychology. "Now We are One again." As God spoke, the three lights merged into a single brilliant mass. The radiance took full possession of the entire room. It was light, but it was also pure love, and it seemed to assume the shape of the space it filled. For a brief moment, I felt an arm enveloping and holding me. Then, just as if a switch had clicked, the light suddenly left the room. The Voices remained, teaching me about God and carefully laying the groundwork for my escape.
>
> It all still seemed so absurd to me, even after all I had experienced during that incredible day. I had so little knowledge of God, of His Word, of His ways. I kept wondering why I had been singled out for all that was happening to me. It was just too much for me to take in. As though my uneasiness and lack of knowledge were understood, the Voices instructed me - separately and together, but always in total agreement and harmony with one another. I could always identify the Person who was speaking, just from the unmistakable sound of His voice. It was the Holy Spirit -the Teacher- who gave the first command. "Tell the guards you have had a rough day and are going to bed early." I laughed out loud. It was like a joke - the understatement of the century. For some reason, God didn't seem to mind that I laughed. I felt like a child, open and innocent and wide-eyed before Him. Though I wasn't in the habit of telling the guards anything, I rose from my bed and knocked on the door to deliver the message. The Follower responded almost most immediately, peering cautiously as he opened the door ajar. "I'm going to bed early, so please don't bother me," I announced, startled at the authority rising in my voice. "I'm very tired." He seemed caught so completely off-guard that I decided to blurt out another question: "Is it possible for me to see Dr. Holmes before I retire?" "No," the Follower stammered," h-h-he left early this afternoon. But I'll tell him ... you want to see him - to see him in the mornin'." He shut the door softly, clicking the dead bolt back in place. I'd never seen a more confused man. I almost felt sorry for him. Almost. As soon as the door was closed, the Lord gave me my next instruction: "Now remove your wig head from its bedside stand, and write on the Styrofoam as I tell you." Each new step seemed more puzzling to me than the last. And I kept wondering if the Follower outside the door was hearing God's voice like I was. I'm sure he hadn't, since he stayed outside the room, but I couldn't understand why. So I took the black wig off the stand, and I wrote a message that God dictated: Dear Dr. Holmes - You may do anything you wish with this head - but leave mine intact. - Dr. Wagner It was as if I was sharing some kind of inside joke with God. I had never thought of Him like that before. He had always been some faraway relic, like many of the religious artifacts I had seen. I was enjoying just being in His presence. Next, God had me place the curly, black wig back on the Styrofoam stand and put it on the bed. Then He showed me exactly how to adjust the pillows below it to resemble my body. In the outlined darkness, it really did look like a person in the bed. "Now, pull the spread up." I smiled at the little details. Since that first hideous day, I had always slept with the blood-stained spread over my head, like a small child hoping that the thin material would keep away my very real boogeymen. "Now, hide behind the curtain," He continued. "At exactly 9:20, the guards will shine a light through the window in the door and think you are fast asleep. They will not make another check tonight." I knew I had to follow every instruction carefully. My life depended upon every word He spoke. The drapes, like the bedspread, were made from drab material designed more for durability than beauty. Still, the drapes were fully lined. I was grateful for the added body and bulk as I hid behind the folds and flattened myself firmly against the window. My nostrils twitched as I stood. I was almost amused at myself, even in the midst of my unfolding life-and-death drama; I stood there wishing I could toss those dusty, foul-smelling drapes into a washing machine until they were fresh and clean again. I made sure that I was completely concealed from the soon-coming gaze of the guards. Even my chic black boots, once shiny, but then caked and stained, were not visible. The years of use had made the drapes sag, even overlapping down on the floor several inches. Once sure that I was as safe as possible, I could do nothing but wait, trying to keep my tense breathing from moving the drapes. I watched the blinking time-and-temperature sign. I hoped it would be the last time I would have to spend the night with my old, continually flashing "friend." As I waited, the Holy Spirit spoke: "Say this after Me -'Lord, I'm one of Your little lost sheep. I've lost my way. Please take me back into the fold.'" What? I thought, "But that's something just like a child would say!" So strange. Nevertheless, I repeated the words. And as I spoke, a rush of power came upon me, so powerful and great. I didn't understand, but I knew there must be some urgent purpose for that surging power. Then I saw the flickering flashlight beam shining briefly through the small window of the locked door. I strained to see the flashing sign across the street. It was 9:20 p.m. Exactly. Just as God had said it would be! Within a split second after the light beam disappeared from the room, Jesus spoke clearly to me: "Now, let us get to work!"

Petti Wagner. Murdered Heiress: Living Witness (Kindle Locations 673-719). Kindle Edition.

---

While this is **not** scripture, it **is** a first-person account, and in my personal judgment is wholly true and reliable.

This also displays well the complete unity of the Trinity that I always imagined, and how they are separate persons, yet a completely unified "God", all at the same time. How wonderful to get this confirmation for myself -- I hope you take it for yourself as well.

Comment: For clarification: My acceptance of the answer does not necessarily endorse _Murdered Heiress_ as legitimate. Nevertheless, your reference to Revelation 3:21 at the beginning of the answer is just the kind of verse I was looking for, which explicitly speaks of Jesus's enthronement as something that's already happened. +1

Answer (score 3):

#### Jesus as God the Son incarnate, at present

Trinitarian and Chalcedonian theology teaches us that incarnation works by God the Son "adding on" a human nature.  It is this added human nature that was **raised to glory after crucifixion**.  Then after ascension, per [Matt 19:28, Matt 25:31, and Luke 1:32](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matt+19%3A28%2C+Matt+25%3A31%2C+Luke+1%3A32&version=ESV) , the glorification continues into God's giving this human nature the **throne of David** as well, which is ***separate*** than the **throne of the Trinitarian God**, the throne from which God the Son came (Phil 2:7).

I think the language "**sitting at the right hand of God the Father**" referred to this same state of Jesus (as God the Son incarnate) ruling on the throne of David as well.

Thus, the answer to your question is YES, Jesus is *already* presently seated at the throne of David, per Eph 1:20-23 as well as St. Stephen's vision in Acts 7:56.  Ligonier's website commentary on Eph 1:20-23 titled [Seated at God's Right Hand](https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/seated-at-gods-right-hand) said:

> ...
>
> In sitting at the right hand of God, Jesus sits on the “throne of his father David” (Luke 1:26–33). He is the Messiah of Israel, “the highest of the kings of the earth” and the fulfillment of the Lord’s promise to keep the offspring of David on the throne forever. (Ps. 89:19–37). We are not waiting for Jesus to enter into His messianic reign, He enjoys it now. All of His enemies are being put under His feet as His gospel is preached and His kingdom expands (1 Cor. 15:20–28).
>
> **Coram Deo**
>
> Even now, Jesus is seated on the throne of His father David at the right hand of God. This means that He is ruler over all and that the kings of the earth rule only according to His sovereign permission. As such, Christ alone is worthy of our highest allegiance, and it is to Him that we must render obedience, even if it means, at times, defying the rulers of this world. Jesus’ kingdom alone is eternal, and His rule is above all others.

#### What we are still anticipating

Two things are still to come: second coming, and our seeing Jesus on the throne of David ruling visibly and explicitly.

- In the second coming Jesus will come as a judge **in glory** unlike during his earthly ministry 2000 years ago, where he appeared as a regular man (consistent with Isa 53:2b: "he had no form or majesty that we should look at him, and no beauty that we should desire him.")
- Then EVERYONE should also see him on the throne of David "sitting at the right hand of God the Father", not just a handful individuals like St. Stephen, ruling His kingdom visibly, not like today (only spiritually, and in "stealth mode").

Comment: @GratefulDiscipleThe Bible stated that when Christ returns the second time (1) all the elements of earth are destroyed (2 P2ter 3:10), hardly a place for ruling. (2) When Christ comes again He will deliver up the Kingdom, not "set up the kingdom." (1 Cor. 15:24).

Answer (score 0):

Acts 2 is definitive on this.  Verses 22-39   specifically verses 24-36.  As king of the eternal kingdom, through Peter - he established the keys to open the kingdom to all mankind in verses 38,39.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Accessories of an 'Enthroned One'** To determine if Christ is enthroned we merely need to see what accessories the Bible said Jesus had been given.

1. He had been given the title, **Lord**. (2 Thess. 2:1 and many other verses).
2. He had been given a **throne** (Luke 1:32, The Lord God shall give Him the throne of His father David.) And Acts 2:34 wrote that the LORD told Jesus to go ahead and "sit down."
3. Jesus Himself declared that "All **power** has been given unto Me in heaven and on earth!" (Matthew 28:18)  This is echoed in Ephesians 1:20-22. "God set Him...far above all principalities, and power, and might, and dominion...not only in this world, but in the world to come!"
4. Jesus said, at the beginning of His ministry, that the **Kingdom** "was at hand." (Matthew 4:17) And later declared, "Some standing here will not taste of death until they see the Son of Man coming in His kingdom." (Matthew 16:28)

Considering all this, there is no doubt Jesus is sitting enthroned in His kingdom. We must not lose sight of the Trinitarian concept of God for it was written that "He is seated at the right hand of God." Nor ignore the necessity of using anthropomorphic language in describing this reality. For the "Three" are still "One."

> And he showed me a pure river of water of life, clear as crystal, proceeding out of the Throne of God and of the Lamb. (Revelation 22:1) (See also Rev. 3:21)

Comment: If Jesus is God, how can he sit on the right hand of God?  Can you sit on your own right hand?

Comment: @Biblasia  The verse reads "at" the right hand, not "on" the hand.  "At the right hand" is human imagery describing a spiritual truth, the fact of Jesus's exaltation as king of the Kingdom of God.

Answer (score 0):

Peace and Blessings Brothers and Sisters in The Body of Christ. I am a Messenger of I AM who calls me Seer. I've come to share the Good News, THE BRIDEGROOM has left THE THRONE and has moved from East to West, HIS Robed covered over the Nations as HE Moved and They were Robed all in White on both sides in multitude with Worship and Praises. The most recent vision was The Wedding Feast and The Leviathan. I am not a scholar in Biblical text or theology. I am just a Believer in I AM who was prophesied to be born for This Hour. I am called SEER and am a Messenger with Gifts. I am sharing the Good News to the world. May I AM Bless you all in your Narrow Way, Sister in Christ Desiree

Comment: Before you post again, I suggest that you take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [ask] and [answer].  What you posted there meets none of those standards.